# Trouble using onPause() method

Tags: android

I have an activity.. when it is calls `onPause()` it starts a new activity.. Problem is when I lock screen of my phone..It calls the `onPause` which cause it to go back to the main activity but I want to stay in that activity.. Is there a way to fix this ?

This is the code snippet if it helps..

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    call_next_activity(call_next_act);
}

private void call_next_activity(Boolean call_next) {
    if (!call_next)
        return;
    Intent select_one;
    if (program_id) {
        select_one = new Intent("c.theworld.com.nikhil.MENU");
    } else {
        select_one = new Intent("c.theworld.com.nikhil.CHAPTER");
        Chapter.call_menu = true;
    }
    startActivity(select_one);
}
```

Comment: the place where you set the final `program_id` that is used to switch might be a better place to switch the activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really, really, really shouldn't put something like that in onPause().

onPause() is a lifecycle indicating the activity is stopping for some reason, the user presses home, back, gets a phone call. Many events outside your control can cause onPuase() to be called.

You should most definitely **not start anything** in the onPause() method, Re-factor your app to work differently is what you need to do.

Comment: Should I not even have finish() method in onPause?

Comment: No, if the activity is about to close it will call onStop() then onDestroy() itself so there is no real need to call finish() in onPause(). Consider this, if a user gets a text message they leave your app to view the text, if you call finish() in onPause() then when they come back to your app, the Activity they were viewing is now gone becuase you called finish() in onPause() which could make a user angry or irritated enough to stop using your app.

Comment: If I don't use finish() ..and use back button to exit my app and I open the app..it doesn't start from the beginning but from that activity! If you see other apps..you see that the app restarts and doesn't start from the current activity

Comment: you can override the back button functionality via onBackPressed(), putting finish() in there is fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to change the logic in the code. An Activity could get stopped due to multiple reasons-pressing home button, incoming call, locking the phone. All will trigger the onPause. So, I suggest you to choose some other alternative when you want to start a new Activity.